# What's the preferable stategy to follow, when using Threads in background in Android Studio?

Tags: android, multithreading, android-studio, android-asynctask, handler

It might be a silly question but I need to ask it to clarify my ideas.
I've studied during my briefly study on Android Development how to set a background Thread.
Now, I've used both Async Task and Handler + Runnable/Message. Which of those two is the most used or better the most recommended?
Thank you so much.

Comment: developers rarely use Async task these days, you might want to look into RXJava or coroutines (if you use Kotlin). They are the best approaches to handle background tasks.

Answer (score 0):

Both the utilities have different functionalities while Async Task is used for background processing for short operations , Handler operates on the main thread for communicating from the background thread.